# Express receives empty request and client does not receive an answer on different ports

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, request

I have a small react client that runs on port 3000 and a small express server that runs on port 3001. When I click a button, a request is sent to the server. However, the POST request prints an empty body and the response is not delivered. The server correctly identifies a POST or GET request though. Chrome's console prints:

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at App.tsx:41:1)
> at App.tsx:41:1
> (anonymous)    @   App.tsx:50
> Promise.catch (async)
> buttonClick2   @   App.tsx:48
> callCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4164
> invokeGuardedCallbackDev   @   react-dom.development.js:4213
> invokeGuardedCallback  @   react-dom.development.js:4277
> invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError    @   react-dom.development.js:4291
> executeDispatch    @   react-dom.development.js:9041
> processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder   @   react-dom.development.js:9073
> processDispatchQueue   @   react-dom.development.js:9086
> dispatchEventsForPlugins   @   react-dom.development.js:9097
> (anonymous)    @   react-dom.development.js:9288
> batchedUpdates$1   @   react-dom.development.js:26140
> batchedUpdates @   react-dom.development.js:3991
> dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem  @   react-dom.development.js:9287
> dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay    @    >react-dom.development.js:6465
> dispatchEvent  @   react-dom.development.js:6457
> dispatchDiscreteEvent

App.tsx (Client)

```
import { Button, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("No Request Sent")

  const data = { username: 'example' };

  const buttonClick = () => {    
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3001', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      }
    ).then(
      (data) => {
        setMsg(data.msg);
        console.log('Success:', data);
        return data;
      }
    ).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    );
  };

  const buttonClick2 = () => {    
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3001', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
    }).then(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      }
    ).then(
      (data) => {
        setMsg(data.msg);
        console.log('Success:', data);
        return data;
      }
    ).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h1">{msg}</Typography>
      <Button onClick={buttonClick}>Click</Button>
      <Button onClick={buttonClick2}>Click2</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server.ts

```
const express = require( "express" );
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1'
}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req:any, res:any) => {
    console.log("GET");
    res.json({msg: 'GET request to the homepage'})
});
  
app.post('/', (req:any, res:any) => {
    console.log("POST: ", req.body);
    res.json({msg: 'POST request to the homepage'})
});

app.listen( port, () => {
    console.log( `server started at http://localhost:${ port }` );
} );
```

What is wrong with this approach or how can I debug it? I've read similar questions/answer but the answer was either related to CORS policy (which I think I took care off) or to the order off my express middleware (which I think I also took care of).

Answer (score 0):

`res.send('GET request to the homepage')` send a string, not JSON. `return response.json();` tries to parse response body as a JSON and fails.

Comment: This doesn't help. The received message body is still empty and the response still causesan error.

Comment: Does `curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "username": "example" }' "http://127.0.0.1:3001"` from terminal returns anything?

Comment: Yes, this returns `{"msg":"POST request to the homepage"}`

Comment: And also the server now prints a message body

Comment: Good, how the response looks in the browser's network inspector?

Comment: The response is empty

Comment: [Here's a screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/yBh6tVC/Screenshot-from-2022-09-08-17-31-44.png) The response tab is empty ("Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier"). However, it seems, as can be seen in the screenshot, that a response is downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, but headers and prefly requests would help more than timings.

Comment: Thanks for your time so far. [Here are the headers](https://i.ibb.co/7kNwsgY/Screenshot-from-2022-09-08-18-28-39.png) I dont know how to access the prefly request (or what they are, for that matter)

Comment: ah, missed this bit - change your cors middleware to `app.use(cors({origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'}));`

Comment: That didnt make a difference

Comment: Did you restart the server and confirmed the response origin header changed?

Comment: I'm running nodemon but I've also manually restarted the server. I added a `console.log(req.headers)` to the server code, [which can be seen here](https://pastebin.com/xMBBp5mL)

Comment: I found the solution: I should not have used `mode: 'no-cors'` in the client, once that was removed everything worked like a charm.